# Linker Error Fatal error detected ILI4368 linking in C++ Builder 6

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I get this error when I link a C++ Builder project. It happens in the IDE and also in the command line tools.
I have been compiling the same project for several years, and now I cannot do it. I installed Windows 8 recently and it could be the reason.

It is C++ Builder 6.

Somebody knows what ILI4368 means?

Thank you